# please give me the solution for shell script

Tags: powershell, shell

Write shell script for the following task

1. Change to /disk1/kafka directory
2. Check if there exists file 'my.pid' is present
3. Output 'pid file not found' if file is not present
4. If the file is present, get contents of this file which will be a PID
5. Check if any process if running with this PID
6. Output 'kafka is running with $PID' if found
7. Output 'kafka is not running with $PID' if not found

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, this is not a software service site. Please read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about a list of `PowerShell` commands for you to research and then you can put this together as a script - come back with more questions if you don't get it working:

1. `Set-Location` or its common alias `cd`
2. `Test-Path`
3. `Write-Host`, `Write-Error`, `Write-Warning`, `Write-Output`
4. `Get-Content`
5. `Get-Process`
6. See 3.
7. See 3.